# Xcode 'clang failed with exit code 1' error when building for test

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to build my project for test but I'm getting this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5eT5.png
[image]

I have read through all threads that I've found but nothing has helped. I have tried specifying the direct path to both the .pch and .plist files under 'build settings'.

This most likely comes up because I've duplicated my project and renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

This line tells you the problem:
[image]

Check your build settings for the ".pch" file. The setting must match the actual file and path.

Try opening the file in the finder, open a new finder window, <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and enter the file address from the build settings, you should be able to open it. Or use Terminal (you will have to quote the path in Terminal).

Beware of the spaces in the file names. I avoid spaces in file and directory names in development because they many times need to be handled in a special manner such as quoting.

Comment: Hey @Zaph. Thanks for the answer, appreciated!
Before posting I found the exact path to both files and copied these into the build settings - and now when I go with your suggestion, it finds the correct file(so path should be correct)
So best shot might be to go away from the space in the project name and changes that all over?

Comment: Yeah, spaces in file/directory names can create problems many times. Things have gotten better but by avoiding embedded spaces I avoid problems.

Comment: I renamed the whole project and let Xcode fix all the name references that it found - still no difference.
the error refers to a .pch file named 'mmmm-Prefix.pch'
now my actual file is called 'OrdsprogSR-Prefix.pch' and in the build settings the whole path for the .pch file goes '/Users/borasmussen/Desktop/Xcode projects/mmmm variation 2/mmmm/OrdsprogSR-Prefix.pch' clearly not mentioning the 'mmmm-Prefix.pch'
Could something somewhere else make xcode look for that other .pch file?

Comment: Make sure you are still getting the pch file error. Delete all derived data (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData 
) and the app from the iPhone and/or simulator (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator). Try this: In BuildSettings go to pch, double-click to open the path window and delete the current path text, select the .pch file in the finder and drag it into the window.

Comment: Same error still - no difference there. I tried dragging it now, still no difference.

I dragged my actual .pch file  'OrdsprogSR-Prefix.pch' but it's still trying to find 'mmmm-Prefix.pch'

Comment: The only thing left is to create a new project and drag the code files into it.